# How to extract non-numeric text from a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

For example, I have this string that could change anytime I only want the alphabetic text from it:

> Ferrari 5 10 15000 -5 0.2

So from that I want "Ferrari".

Sometimes there won't be a space between "Ferrari" and the numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string str = "Ferrari 5 10 15000 -5 0.2";
string text = Regex.Match(str, @"[a-zA-Z\s]+").Value.Trim();
```

By also matching whitespace and then trimming the result, It will match `"Some Car"` in `"Some Car 5 10 ..."`.

Comment: Using `@"\b[a-zA-Z\s]+\b"` returns `"Ferrari "`.  The reason there's added complexity (allowing whitespace and then trimming) is that I figured multi-word 'columns' might be useful, so I allowed for whitespace in the pattern.  You could probably make it work without grabbing the extra space using a lookahead or something, but personally (without any other reason to do so) I'd just prefer a `.Trim()`.  The intent is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can just match the initial letters like so

```
string text = "Ferrari 5 10 15000 -5 0.2";
string pat = @"([a-z]+)";

// Instantiate the regular expression object.
Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
Match m = r.Match(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
String s = Regex.Match(str, @"[a-zA-Z]+").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert to a char array and pull out the letters and then convert back to a string:

```
string text = "Ferrari 5 10 15000 -5 0.2";
string alphas = string.Join( "", text.ToCharArray().Where( char.IsLetter ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the times when Regular Expressions come in handy :

```
Regex wordMatcher = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+");
foreach(Match m in wordMatcher.Matches("Ferrari 55 100000 24 hello"))
    MessageBox.Show(m.Value);
```

Essentially all The RegEx does is attempt to match groups of letters between a-z ignoring case.

Answer (score 1):

If it will always end with [digits, -, ., and spaces], you can use `.TrimEnd`:

```
record.TrimEnd("0123456789 .-".ToCharArray());
```

... or if there's no spaces in the text you care about, you can read until the first space ...

```
var whatINeed = new string(record.TakeWhile(c => c != ' ').ToArray());
```

... or just take the first item when split on spaces ...

```
var whatINeed = record.Split().First();
```